# Menu router question

Tags: performance, drupal, drupal-6, menu

My question is related to a performance issue I'm experiencing using the context module with a large number of menus. The performance issue may be a result of a module I created to import a menu structure from a different CMS into Drupal. I programatically created the menu items using `menu_link_save()`, passing in the menu_name, link_path (node/$nid), link_title, plid, and weight. The router_path that gets assigned to these is "node/%".

My performance issue appears to be that the context module is calling `menu_link_load()` for every menu item that exists (there are quite a few), and from that calling `node_load()` because of way the router_path is set.

In trying to troubleshoot this, I see there is a router_path of "node" in the database which has a different access_callback and access_arguments than "node/%". **What is the difference between these two router_paths, how do they relate to one another, and when does one get called vs. the other?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The path 'node' shows all nodes wich are set to active&frontpage, it is also the default path for your frontpage for this reason.
The path 'node/%' is for viewing 1 specific node with id = %.